# HL7 FSH IG Publisher java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space issue

Tags: java, out-of-memory, hl7-fhir

I have upgraded the FSH publisher.jar to 1.3.28 and getting the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:188)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read0(StreamDecoder.java:137)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:122)
    at java.base/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:169)
    at org.hl7.fhir.utilities.TextFile.streamToString(TextFile.java:177)
    at org.hl7.fhir.r4.formats.JsonParserBase.loadJson(JsonParserBase.java:220)
    at org.hl7.fhir.r4.formats.JsonParserBase.parse(JsonParserBase.java:130)
    at org.hl7.fhir.convertors.loaders.loaderR5.R4ToR5Loader.loadResource(R4ToR5Loader.java:114)
    at org.hl7.fhir.r5.context.SimpleWorkerContext$PackageResourceLoader.loadResource(SimpleWorkerContext.java:112)
    at org.hl7.fhir.r5.context.CanonicalResourceManager$CanonicalResourceProxy.getResource(CanonicalResourceManager.java:80)
    at org.hl7.fhir.r5.context.CanonicalResourceManager$CachedCanonicalResource.getResource(CanonicalResourceManager.java:140)
    at org.hl7.fhir.r5.context.CanonicalResourceManager.getList(CanonicalResourceManager.java:618)
    at org.hl7.fhir.r5.context.BaseWorkerContext.fetchResourcesByType(BaseWorkerContext.java:2014)
    at org.hl7.fhir.igtools.renderers.ValueSetRenderer.xref(ValueSetRenderer.java:106)
    at org.hl7.fhir.igtools.publisher.Publisher.generateOutputsValueSet(Publisher.java:10579)
    at org.hl7.fhir.igtools.publisher.Publisher.generateResourceHtml(Publisher.java:9727)
    at org.hl7.fhir.igtools.publisher.Publisher.generateHtmlOutputs(Publisher.java:9593)
    at org.hl7.fhir.igtools.publisher.Publisher.generate(Publisher.java:7053)
    at org.hl7.fhir.igtools.publisher.Publisher.createIg(Publisher.java:1103)
    at org.hl7.fhir.igtools.publisher.Publisher.execute(Publisher.java:933)
    at org.hl7.fhir.igtools.publisher.Publisher.main(Publisher.java:11666)
```

I have tried updating the jvm arguments as well with the following command but still it takes around 1hr 20 mins to build the project even though the project was building in 30 minutes earlier.

> JAVA -Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -jar "..\input-cache%publisher_jar%" -ig . %*

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

-Xmx2048M is extremely low for running the publisher.  It's quite possible you're just hitting the memory limitations of the process.  (The publisher is loading all of the UTG terminology, all of the core specification profiles, all the standard extensions, plus any of your dependent IGs before it even starts to load your own content.)  Typically you'd want at least a 16 GB machine and more is better.